# NDB 'put' values not persisting?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I just started experiencing this issue. I have not changed anything but suddenly it seems after doing a put after changing a value, the value does not persist when I later look it up in the database or do a query in the console. But this only happens SOMETIMES.

So I have this model like:

```
class User(IXBase, flask_security.UserMixin):
   .....
   current_challenge = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=1)
```

I have added logs to a _post_put_hook and print out the values. I see the EXPECTED value there (in this case a 5 for current_challenge)

```
User(key=Key('User', 'o@k.ay'), active=True, created=datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 15, 2, 2, 25, 854790), current_challenge=5,
```

However, if I print this value out I will sometimes see the value it was at previously. (in this case I see 4). But again only sometimes do I see the previous value, sometimes it increments correctly, but it seems to have just started happening recently and from what I can tell I have not changed anything.

So if I do this it seems like that value does not get saved.

```
u = ndb.Key('User', 'o@k.ay').get()

print u.current_challenge
```

Any thoughts on how this could happen? I can post more code.

But this is the code responsible for incrementing the challenge:

```
    def increment_challenge(self, session):
        self.current_challenge += 1
        self.put()
        return
```

This gets called from an endpoint like:

```
@blueprint.route('/upload_report',  methods=['POST'])
@flask_security.roles_required('user')
def upload_session_report():
  user = flask_login.current_user
  updated_challenge = user.update_challenges()
```

Where update_challenges does some other calculations and figures out if it should call increment challenge (which is also a method on 'user')

Any help would be great!

Comment: i suppose you already know that the datastore is eventually consistant? if not, thats your answer.

Comment: Right, but it does not seem to ever sync up. Even an hour later the value is still incorrect.

Comment: the first thing I would do is get the key of the entity you just put, and explicitly `get` it using that key.  If it is seccessfully retrieved you know there is now problem with your puts

Answer (score 0):

Use a [transaction](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions):

```
@ndb.transactional
def increment_challenge(self, session):
    self.current_challenge += 1
    self.put()
    return
```